# update form by retrieving it using a condition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to rails.. I want to update the data which matches my condition.. I have a form which submits two values(order_no, order_date)., and i want to retrieve all the data which relates to that order_no.. I dont know to write the controller code for this . Can someone help me.. here is my code.. I am really sorry if you feel this doubt is silly. I really dont know how to code efficiently in rails.
  //my view

```
<%= form_for([@order], :url=>{:controller=>"users"}) do |i|%>
<tr><td><%= i.label :order_no,"Order No" %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%= i.text_field :order_no %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%= i.label :order_date,"Order Date" %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%= i.text_field :order_date %></td></tr>
<%= link_to "Update",users_update_orderSummary_path(i) %>
<% end %>
```

my controller,

```
def edit_order
@order=Order.find params[:id]
end

def update_order
@order=Order.find params[:id]
@order=Order.where(order_no = params[:order_no])
if @order.update_attributes(order_params)
  flash[:success] = "Order updated"
  redirect_to :action=>"login"
else
  render "edit_order"
end
end
```

And I am getting the following error..

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#update_orderSummary
>   Couldn't find Order with 'id'=

Kindly please help me..

Comment: can you provide your routes?

Comment: You shouldn't be having a link in the form, instead you should have a submit button.

Comment: users_show_orderSummary GET    /users/show_orderSummary(.:format)   users#show_orderSummary
  users_view_orderSummary GET    /users/view_orderSummary(.:format)   users#view_orderSummary
        users_show_labour GET    /users/show_labour(.:format)         users#show_labour
        users_view_labour POST   /users/view_labour(.:format)         users#view_labour
users_update_orderSummary POST   /users/update_orderSummary(.:format) users#update_orderSummary
  users_edit_orderSummary PATCH  /users/edit_orderSummary(.:format)   users#edit_orderSummary

Comment: use rails g scaffold order, it will help you to generate controller and views and update routes automatically, then study the code

Comment: I will try this Chaitanya and will intimate problem., if any. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your `order` actions into a separate controller:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :orders, only: [:edit, :update], module: :users #-> url.com/orders/:id/edit

#app/controllers/users/orders_controller.rb
class Users::OrdersController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @order = Order.find params[:id]
   end

   def update
      @order  = Order.find params[:id]
      @orders = Order.where order_no: params[:order][:order_no]
      if @orders.update_all order_params
         redirect_to action: :logic, success: "Order Updated"
      end
   end

   private

   def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:order_no, :order_date)
   end
end

#app/views/users/orders/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :order_no %>
    <%= f.text_field :order_date %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

Your main problem is that you're trying to do two things with the `update` method -- `Order.find` && `Order.where`.

You can't update both - you have to do one.

I have used [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all), which can be used on your `Order.where` collection; if you wanted to update a single object, just use `@order.update`

Comment: Thank you Rich. your answer solved my confusion..  Thankyou

Comment: If it solved the question, you should at least upvote, perhaps accept the answer. Leaving without any solution will confuse future readers